# numpy sklearn import error

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

When running  from python console the following code works fine'

However when trying to use the same code in a myxxx.py  it does not:

```
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
print(iris.xx)
```

when testing sklearn  it reports no failures
however when testing numpy I get 16 or so failures.

I don't know if these failures are related to my error or not.

This is on a windoes8.1 x64 machine.

So why would the code typed directly into the python console work but not from the file ( meaning it fails in spyder and python myfile.py)?

the error states something like unable to import numpy datasets. Sounds like some type of name clash or scope issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what sort of errors? They might be mighty informative.

Comment: The question stated it was an import error, sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: The error states: unable to import datasets:

Comment: this is the actual error: TpeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: It does work from the console but not from reading a script

Comment: PROBLEM RESOLVED. USING THE OBJECT INSPECTOR I came up with 2 resolutitons

Comment: 1) digits = datasets.base.load_digits()   so we had base call                                                                                                                2)  from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
digits = load_digits()
print(digits.data)